# Can I limit write permission to table entries only for authenticated users, while allowing the app to create new entries?

Tags: unit-testing, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I only want my application to be able to add new users to the database?  Then, I only want the authenticated user to be able to edit their entries.  What should the security rules look like for the firebase realtime database?

I know about firebase app check and I am happy to implement it, but I don't know if that is the only option.

Comment: Asking for the best way to do something is typically not going to lead to great answers here on Stack Overflow. I recommend reading https://overflow.tips/problematic-questions#what-is-the-besteasiestfastest-way-to-do-x. To learn how to write security rules, check out the documentation (and linked video) [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security) and [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/get-started).